# Is there a way to implement a touch and hold in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to make something happen while a finger is being held on the screen.

What I'm trying to do is hold my finger on the screen and make an object rotate(Y axis only), while the finger is still on the screen. The rotation should stop when the finger is lifted.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateObs : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotateSpeed;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the object should be rotating while my finger(on PC it works with mouse too) is on the screen.

What happens is - it rotates for 1 frame only and then stops. It registers it like it's a single tap, it doesn't matter if my finger is still on the screen or not.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong, I just can't see where.

Comment: if it helps, there is a [gamedev stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) forum where there is a lot of unity questions asked.

Comment: I didn't know that. I'll look further into it. Thank you.

Comment: The reason it only rotates for 1 frame is that you are only testing to see when the touch begins. You need a different event to check that the finger is still on screen (as someone else answered). The touch phase changes the next frame after the initial touch. You can check for both begin/stationary if you want to make sure it starts rotating on the first frame when you touch instead of delaying by 1 frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect if the user is holding the mouse button, you should use

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    transform.Rotate (Vector3.up * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

In fact, this line of code will work even in mobile, but in case if you want to work with Touches,

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    Touch first = Input.GetTouch (0);
    if (first.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary) 
    {
        transform.Rotate (Vector3.up * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: The object rotates successfully with Input.GetMouseButton(0), however the second code you suggest does not work - if (first.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary). 

Afaik touch is simulated with mouse on the PC so it should work, but it doesn't

Comment: Well I just built the project and ran it on an Android device and using the second version of code, using Touches - works! This is so weird, how am I supposed to test a game if every time I need to try some behavior I have to port it to a mobile device?

Comment: @LeeJaedong how about using [UnityRemote](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote5.html)?

Comment: @LeeJaedong It is easy bro, just implement the two if conditions on your code, I am sorry for not clarifying it

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem . I wanted to rotate my player around a point if the user was holding the screen . Touch to the right moves the player clockwise and vice versa.
Here's the code :

```
 void Update()
{
    if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector3 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
        touchPos.z = 0f;
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
        {
            if (touchPos.x > 0)
                movement = 1f;
            else if (touchPos.x < 0)
                movement = -1f;
        }
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            movement = 0f;
        }
        
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.RotateAround(centre, Vector3.forward, movement * Time.fixedDeltaTime * -moveSpeed);
}
```